# multi value for the same param on sql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data

i'm not sure if is possible..but i want to join this 2 sql query in one and get all results:

```
select cod from services,services_has_tab2 where services.id=services_has_tab2.services_id and services_has_tab2.tab2_id= "1"
```

and

```
select cod from services,services_has_tab2 where services.id=services_has_tab2.services_id and services_has_tab2.tab2_id= "2"
```

in my program Java (spring) i have:

```
List<String> strLst  = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForList(sql2,new Object[] {"1,2"},String.class);
```

but not work with "1,2" i have only result for the first param (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN`.

```
SELECT cod 
FROM   services, 
       services_has_tab2 
WHERE  services.id = services_has_tab2.services_id 
       AND services_has_tab2.tab2_id IN ( "1", "2" );
```